# Circular dependency of a child class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, circular-dependency, activesupport

Suppose we are using Rails or just `ActiveSupport::Dependencies` module. Now lets look to this code:

animal.rb

```
class Animal
  CHILD = {
    cat: Cat
  }

  # factory!?
  def self.child(name)
    CHILD[name].new
  end
end
```

cat.rb

```
class Cat < Animal
end
```

dog.rb

```
class Dog < Animal
end
```

Somewhere before all the classes are loaded:

```
Cat.new
```

That code will result in a `B is not a class (TypeError)` (activesupport 3.x) or `Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant B` (activesupport 4.x) because it wasn't created yet, but the name of the class already in a class table.

To solve this problem it's possible to `require 'a'`, then `A` will require `B`.

Can give me some better solution to the following issue?

Comment: Can you give a better idea of what you intend to do? In general, I can think of very few reasons why a class would need to know about its own subclasses.

Comment: Circular references are trouble unless you have a specific use case that requires it. Usually the problem can be resolved in other ways - what is your need for a circular dependency?

Comment: @dsatch, I'm setting mapping hash CONSTANT with children classes in the parent class. As a solution I can move constant to the method where it's used, but I don't think it's a proper way.

Comment: Just realized it's just a factory pattern. But anyway, I guess the above solution is the best solution to have: CONST is in the class level (it can be reused), and the `child` method is a factory method, that are constructing the correct class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid circular dependencies if you do not want / can't use `require`. One way to avoid them is replacing class loading level calls with runtime level ones:

```
class Animal
  CHILD = {
    cat: 'Cat'
  }

  def self.child(name)
    CHILD[name].constantize.new
  end
end
```

Indeed `self.child` can't be called at class level now, or you will be in a circular dependency context again.

Comment: Looks good and I feel it's only thing I can expect to improve.

Answer (score 2):

For this reason, and to avoid autoloading a ton of other classes at either Rails initialization or when a specific class is loaded, Rails uses a string to specify the class name of an association if required to be specified, e.g.

```
has_many :published_posts, class_name: 'Post'
```

because associations have the greatest tendency to have interactions like this.

So, if you have control over what you use and can delay load of a constant until it is needed in Ruby/Rails by using a string to hold the name of the constant until you need to constantize it, it might not be a bad idea. But, like anything, the best solution depends on your requirements.

This may seem wierd if you are coming from another programming language background like Java where historically, at least, developers would *avoid* using reflection to dynamically instantiate a class from a String because of the overhead (at least in older versions) and the possibility of errors when loading the class later versus catching them early-on at startup. But, it really isn't a bad thing here. And this also doesn't stop you from eager loading as much as you want up-front, because really what it is doing is eliminating the direct dependency caused by constant reference during the load.

Comment: Great, but in my example I'm using ActiveAdmin, that is initializing the models right after it gets initialized through the routes. I've updated my example to more realistic use case.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, since you changed the question, my answer looks incorrect, but will leave it as-is. Basically, the idea is that to avoid circular dependencies, you can store the constant as a string and constantize sometime after class load. You may even want to cache/store the constant after constantizing, if it makes things more efficient.